# how to update the spinner values while clicking on button in android?

Tags: android

my app have a spinner and also have reset button. how to update the values while clicking on button?

Comment: More details please! What should clicking the reset button do to the spinner?

Answer (score 10):

Set a new adapter on the `Spinner` via `setAdapter()`. Or, if it is an `ArrayAdapter`, use `add()`, `insert()`, and `remove()` to modify the data. Or, if it is a `CursorAdapter`, `requery()` it to get fresh data.

Since you elected not to tell us what "update the values" means, we can only guess.

Comment: Followed your advice (but used clear method of ArrayAdpater). For me this answer should have been marked accepted!

Comment: Modifying the data or setting a new adapter on the spinner doesn't force the drop down selection menu to refresh automatically.

Comment: I get UnsupportedOperationException using remove().

Comment: @Klaasvaak: That is because your `ArrayAdapter` is not wrapping a mutable `ArrayList`.

Answer (score 0):

Change the underlying data and call the notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter.

```
          list.clear();
          list.add("A");
              list.add("B");
          dataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```